# Angular mat tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to show an array of elements as a list with mat-angular tooltip.

This is **app.component.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button
      matTooltip={{items}}
      aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
      Action
</button>
```

This is **app.component.ts**

```
items=['A','B,'C']
```

I am able to display them as ',' separated values from the above, but I need them as a list with each element in a new line

Thanks

Comment: In tooltip you have to always using string. Here items is array.

Comment: I am able to use items array and the elements are displayed in a way that they are separated with ','

Comment: Try toString() with '\n.

Comment: You might want to consider using a Pipe instead of modifying the string. It's a more "reusable" (maybe more "angular") approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53198157/9226213. The Pipe can of course be modified to handle any kind of tootlip "value" content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to display the array in each new line, then The **[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)** suggests ::ng-deep is deprecated but it still works with the latest version

Also you need to break line after each word, so you can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to do that,

```
 items=['A','B','C'];
 newItems = this.items.join("\r\n");
```

Here is the [STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrrwqb-mydve2?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

Comment: Awesome Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method of an `Array` to join an array of strings with an optional parameter used for the delimiter (by default, it's set to `,`):

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        [matTooltip]="items.join()"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
</button>
```

Comment: I tried [matTooltip]="items.join('/n') but it didnt work

Comment: @bhargavinadendla It should be a backslash (\), not a forward slash (/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this work for me
app.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button
   matTooltip={{items.toString()}}
   aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">Action
</button>
```

app.component.ts

items=['A','B,'C']

Comment: are you import MatTooltipModule?

Comment: @bhargavinadendla can you confirm you want output like this link:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LuGkDlnqQiedXEpUyBaKTRDu8a242QuT